# when i go to update the picture ic cloudinary it gives error "no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cloudinary

when i go to update the picture ic cloudinary it gives error "no such file or directory , open D:/web development/mern-stack-project-course-commerce/backend/undefine

please help and check images

[backend cloudinary code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s8YH.png)
[throow This Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnITj.png)

i expect my problem slove this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing is thrown by the NodeJS code which is part of the Cloudinary Node JS SDK and indicates that there is either no file at the path you provided ('D:/web development/mern-stack-project-course-commerce/backend/undefine') - this actually might be the issue since undefined is not an image, or there is a file but the permissions do not allow your code to open the file.

May I please ask you to double-check the path and if there is in fact a file there and what permissions it has? Perhaps you actually wanted a relative path?

You could also try to pass a path to a file that you definitely know exists and has the correct permissions and see if you can upload that.